# mutate_at() or map_dfr(), changing multiple columns at once

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that Looks like

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('id_1','id_2', 'id_3'), 
                 m_1 = c(1,2,3), 
                 m_2 = c(2,3,5), 
                 m_3 = c(2,6,4))
```

```
change = function(x){ 
 if(x == 2){
  tmp = 'great'
  }else{
  tmp ='bad'
  } 
  return(tmp)
}
```

I want to apply the *change function* on m_1, m_2, and m_3 without having to repeat the function over and over again.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("m_"),
                ~ifelse(. == 2, "great", "bad")))

    id   m_1   m_2   m_3
1 id_1   bad great great
2 id_2 great   bad   bad
3 id_3   bad   bad   bad
```